# How to receive a list of values after Wavelet Packet Transform in Python using PyWavelets and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I'm trying to perform a Wavelet Packet Transform in Python. Therefore I want to convert a list of frequencies into a wavelet packet. The result I am trying to get is a new **list** of values to produce a plot later on and here lies the problem.

Here is the important part my code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pywt
```

```py
print("starting wavelet packet transform...")

timeList = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
frequencyList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

##########################
# Wavelet Packet Transform
##########################
wp = pywt.WaveletPacket(data=frequencyList, wavelet='db1', mode='symmetric', maxlevel=3)
wp = np.array(wp)
print(timeList.size)
print(wp.size)

print("terminating wavelet packet transform...")
```

Please note that all lists (`timeList`, `frequencyList` and `wp`) are already converted to **numpy arrays**. The values of the lists are also just an example.

I used **PyWavelets** to perform the wavelet packet transform on my `frequencyList`.

If I want to check the size of the two arrays `wp` and `timeList` (*see code above*) this is the result I am receiving:

```
starting wavelet packet transform...
Size of timeList:  9
Size of wp:  1
terminating wavelet packet transform...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anyone explain, why the size of `wp` is ***1*** and not ***9***? If I print the `wp` I receive a plot of ***9*** values...

I'm more than grateful for any sort of help.

Tanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hey, please make sure to check out the documentation of the library you're using.  https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/regression/wp.html tldr WaveletPacket is a class and the constructor returns an instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I already checked the docks. But I don't understand why I get all the values if I print ```wp```... I get all the values in form of a list in my output window.

Comment: The data you're looking for is contained in the data attribute. As to why it prints that, you'd have to look at its __repr__ method.

Comment: Since `wp` can't be represented as some internal numpy dtype, it remains an object and `np.array(wp)` contains that one element. `print(wp)` calls the `__str__` method of the class, which returns  `self.path + ": " + str(self.data)`

Comment: That's exactly what I receive thanks a lot! Is there a way to make a list out of the Wavelet Packet? Or am I walking completely in the wrong direction? Sorry if I am asking but I'm a complete beginner...